# How to store raster brick in memory, rather than on disk in R?

Tags: raster, r

I am trying to run analysis on the yearly weather data files here: https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/. I'm running into a problem where each yearly file for each variable requires 2.4GB memory if I read it in using ncdf4 package. I can use the raster packages brick function to create a pointer to the file on disk, but this is very slow.

How do I store a raster brick in my computer's memory, rather than just create a pointer? Also, does anyone have ideas on how to reduce the size of these files in R (they're about 100MB on disk)?

Answer (score 2):

To load all values in `RasterBrick` into RAM you can use `readAll`

```
library(raster)
b <-brick("tmmn_2020.nc")
x <- readAll(b)
```

But this will not help you if you cannot have that much data in RAM, as you say.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit unclear what you want to do. Anyway you could use `raster::stack()` rather than `raster::brick()` to store multi-layer raster and saving time. While if you want to store the pointers with little memory usage you could read files as a raster stack or brick and save them as .rds file with `saveRDS()`.

```
library(raster)
s<-stack("tmmn_2020.nc")
b<-brick(s)#this is slow
saveRDS(s,"stack.rds")
saveRDS(b,"brick.rds")
#read back
r <- readRDS("stack.rds")
```

To reduce file size on disk you can try to compress them while saving. Something similar to

```
writeRaster(s,"stack.tif",progress='text',option=c('COMPRESS=LWZ'))
writeRaster(b,"brick.tif",progress='text',option=c('COMPRESS=LWZ'))
```

But when you use compression, the biggest trade-off is extra processing time which is required to uncompress the image, and after uncompressing, the image would still consume the same amount of memory.
In your case, however, it seems to me that the original files are already heavily compressed, I don't think you can do better with the raster package.
There is the new `terra` package that implements lots of functionalities of the `raster` package, speeding up computation and reducing memory usage, but for your data, I think the best option is to lose some time to convert files to brick and saving as rds file with `saveRDS()`. For instance, I've downloaded the "tmmn_2020.nc" file (146 MB), which is a 366 multi-bands raster. Reading it in r with `raster::stack()` or `terra::rast()` it's instant, and saving the resulting file with `saveRDS()` took 0.1 seconds on my PC, resulting in an 8 Kb file (because it is a pointer).

```
library(terra)
t <- rast("tmmn_2020.nc")
saveRDS(t,"tstack.rds")
t <- readRDS("tstack.rds")
```

Comment: If you can use `raster::brick("file")` then you should use it in favor of `raster::stack("file")` as it is more efficient. Also, it is not wise to use `saveRDS` with either type because, as you point out, you save a pointer to a file that may be no longer be around.

Comment: And I should add that saving SpatRaster to a rds is always very bad advice. SpatRaster actually uses true "pointers" (i.e. a C++ construct) that are not valid after reading from a rds. So you really should never do that. With smaller files you could do `saveRDS(pack(x))`.  (`raster`  objects just store the filename, and as long the file still exists the object remains valid)